# Accessing JSTL variable in jsp of calculation in JSTL

Tags: java, jsp, jstl, el

In jsp i have this portion and works fine

```
<c:forEach var="info" items="${infoList}" >
<tr>
    <td>${info.key} </td>
    <td>${info.total}</td>
    <td>${info.delay}</td>
</tr>
</c:forEach>
```

here `infoList` comes from struts action class which is a `ArrayList` of Class `Info`

```
public class Info{
private String key;
private String total;
private String delay

}
```

Now i need to add another `<td>` which will print the percentage calculated like   ${info.delay}*100/${info.total} but will print exactly two digit after decimal.

I tried this

```
${ info.totalDelay*100/info.totalShipment }
```

which print the percentage but can't limit to 2 digit. In java i can use

```
NumberFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#0.00");
```

But how i will do that i here because in in `<% %> (jap tag)` i cant use `${}`

**Can i access those variable in `<% %>` some how Or can i use `formatter .format()` in a `<c:>` tag**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using JSTL [Format Number](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jstl_format_formatnumber_tag.htm)

```
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
<fmt:formatNumber type="number" minFractionDigits="2" maxFractionDigits="2" value="${ info.totalDelay*100/info.totalShipment } " />
```

Comment: Better than any solution. defiantly deserve ++ . thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well i figured it out

in the top i did this :

```
<%
 NumberFormat numberFormat=new DecimalFormat("#.##");
%>
```

And i the td i did this:

```
<td>
<c:set var="tl" value="${info.total}"></c:set>
<c:set var="dl" value="${info.delay}"></c:set>
<jsp:useBean id="tl" class="java.lang.String"/> 
<jsp:useBean id="dl" class="java.lang.String"/> 

<%
     out.println(numberFormat.format(Double.parseDouble(dl)*100/Integer.parseInt(tl)));
%>
</td>
```